# How to show tag/skill type to a dynamic post in Wordpress theme Classica

Tags: wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming

I use this theme:
http://demo.themezilla.com/?theme=classica

Under the "recent projects" i want each posted portfolio post to  display what kind of tag/skill-type it is connected to. This can be checked in the wp-admin page when you create a new portfolio post. I don't know what function i need to write in php to make this work.
Is there any easy way to solve this like when you show a posts excerpt?

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?
```

Comment: Is it stored as custom post meta data?

Comment: `<?php if($terms) : foreach ($terms as $term) { echo 'term-'.$term->term_id.' '; } endif; ?>` This will show up as "term-4" or "term-3" but not as the name of the skill-type

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use like this.

```
<?php the_tags( '<p>Tags: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?>
```

Comment: Cant seem to make it work :( I think this theme needs to call for some other function.

Answer (score 0):

If it's stored as a custom variable (appears below the post content when editing it in the admin panel), you can usually access it like so:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key_name_here', true);
```

Check out the [get_post_meta() Code Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) for more details on the function.

Comment: `<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, __( 'skill-type' ), '', ', ',''); ?>` This works. But it is a link. How to make this as plain text without link?

Answer (score 0):

Use get_the_term_list() to get the skill-type and strip_tags() to remove the links

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'skill-type', '', ', ','' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );
```